# Why Android HttpURLConnection is not able to create Asset on Azure Media Services using REST API?

Tags: java, android, rest, azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to create an Asset on Azure Media Services using REST API from Android. I am following [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-upload-files#upload-assets) and this is my code to connect with AMS endpoint from Android,

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) this._url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", String.valueOf("application/json"));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("DataServiceVersion", String.valueOf("1.0;NetFx"));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("MaxDataServiceVersion", String.valueOf("3.0;NetFx"));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", String.valueOf("application/json"));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", String.valueOf("UTF-8"));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "Bearer %s", _token));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-version", String.valueOf(2.11));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("x-ms-client-request-id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Host", this._host);
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(this._postData.length));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Expect", String.valueOf("100-continue"));

    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIME_OUT);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_READ_TIME_OUT);
    urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    OutputStream wr= urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    wr.write(_postData);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

And my `_postData` variable is byte array which I am converting from json,

```
_fileName = _fileName.replace(" ", "-");

    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
    jo.put("Name", _fileName+".mp4");
    jo.put("Options", String.valueOf(0));

    this._postData = jo.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");
```

I have tried using Google Chrome's REST api client extension to check the post request and It works fine. I got the response I was expecting from chrome's REST api client extension but using Android, I am not getting the same response. I am getting [this response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/media-services-rest-get-started#a-idconnectaconnect-to-the-media-services-account-with-rest-api) from this code which is the step I have already performed before running this code. I have used both endpoints `https://media.windows.net/` and `https://wamsbayclus001rest-hs.cloudapp.net/` but it is not working from Android. I believe that Android is changing Headers or something is wrong with headers that AMS not parsing properly. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this using Android `HttpUrlConnection`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing `OutputStream` to `DataOutputStream`

```
DataOutputStream wrr = new DataOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wrr.write(this._postData);
        wrr.flush();
        wrr.close();
```

and changed my json array to string,

`String s = "{\"Name\":\"" + _fileName + ".mp4\", \"Options\":\"0\"}";`

and it worked fine.